# SQL select from a Case when generated field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my query there's this field is generated by this statement

```
CASE WHEN T1.unitMsr='MT' then STR((T1.Quantity),12,5) 
ELSE STR((T1.Quantity*T2.NumInSale),12,5)END as OrderQty,

isnull(str(sum(CASE WHEN TN.unitMsr = 'MT' 
Then TN.Quantity ELSE TN.Quantity*T2.NumInSale END),8,5),'0.00000') as DO_Qty_MT,
```

before the select statement ends, i would like to achieve something like this

```
Case When DO_Qty_MT >= OrderQty Then 'Normal'
Else 'Abnormal' END
As 'Closing method'
```

How should i substitute DO_Qty_MT and OrderQty with proper referencing?

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? please just tag one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are setting the order as "abnormal" if total order quantity is less than any of the order rows..
But this is possible only when `T1.Quantity` or `T2.NumInSale` are `NULL` or negative (when `OrderQty<0`).

Starting from you `TN` table you can simply test rows using:

```
-- get all rows with detailed information and Normal/Abnormal test..
select 
    *, Case When isnull(OrderQty, -1)<0 Then 'Abnormal' Else 'Normal' END As [Closing method]
from  TN
```

Even simpler if you need only *"Abnormal"* rows

```
select *, 'Abnormal' As [Closing method]
from  TN
where isnull(OrderQty, -1)<0
```

If you just want to extract Orders with abnormal rows use `distinct YourOrderId` instead of `*` in previous queries.

```
-- get all orders with Normal/Abnormal test
select distinct OrderId, 
    Case When isnull(OrderQty, -1)<0 Then 'Abnormal' Else 'Normal' END As [Closing method]
from  TN

-- get only Abnormal orders
select distinct OrderId, 'Abnormal' As [Closing method]
from  TN
where isnull(OrderQty, -1)<0
```

Answer (score 0):

The typical ways to add in such "variables" is to use a CTE or subquery.  An alternative is a lateral join, which SQL Server supports with the `apply` keyword:

```
select . . ., v.OrderQty,
       coalesce(str(sum(case when TN.unitMsr = 'MT'
                             then TN.Quantity 
                             else TN.Quantity * T2.NumInSale  
                        end), 8, 5
                   ), '0.00000'
               ) as DO_Qty_MT,
from . . . outer apply
     (values (case when T1.unitMsr = 'MT' then str(T1.Quantity, 12, 5) 
                   else str(T1.Quantity * T2.NumInSale, 12, 5)
              end)
     ) v(OrderQty)
```

This makes it simpler to do chains of calculations.

Also, I don't understand why you are using `str()`.  `Decimal`/`numeric` would seem to do what you want -- and keep the representation of the value as a *number* not a *string*.